Unable to publish event between microservices with Axon framework
I'm trying to learn Axon Framework/Server for sending events between microservices, so that I can build a saga orchestration pattern. I've already implemented CreateModelCommand and ModelAggregate. I can trigger the create command and see that command is being triggered, on the Axon Dashboard. But I don't see anything about the ModelCreatedEvent. I want to publish it, so that the other microservice can retrieve that event and create a model.
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CreateModelCommand {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private String sagaId;

    private String name;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Aggregate
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ModelAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String sagaId;

    private String name;

    @CommandHandler
    public ModelAggregate(CreateModelCommand command) {
        ModelCreatedEvent event = new ModelCreatedEvent(
                command.getSagaId(),
                command.getName()
        );
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(event);
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(ModelCreatedEvent event) {
        this.sagaId = event.getSagaId();
        this.name = event.getName();
    }
}

The event below is shared with both microservices.
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ModelCreatedEvent {

    private String sagaId;

    private String name;
}

@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> createUser(@RequestBody RequestBody requestBody) {
        String sagaId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        CreateModelCommand command = new CreateModelCommand(
                sagaId,
                requestBody.name()
        );
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(command);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(new ResponseBody(UUID.randomUUID()));
    }
}

@Saga
public class ModelProcessingSaga {

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "sagaId")
    @StartSaga
    private void handle(ModelCreatedEvent event) {
        log.info("SAGA STARTED: %s".formatted(event.toString()));
    }
}

I have an EventHandler that listens for ModelCreatedEvent in the second microservice, and that method calls, model creation method according to the events properties. When I send a post request CreateModelCommand is being triggered but I don't see any published ModelCreatedEvent.
I don't know if this is a proper way to design microservices, I'm just trying to orchestrate creation commands in one place, so that I can easily handle relational models more easily.

I have a couple of recommendations for you, Oğuz Öztınaz.
1. Testing Aggregates and Sagas
Firstly, Axon Framework comes with Test Fixtures, for both Aggregates and Sagas. If you construct a TestFixture for your ModelAggregate and ModelProcessingSaga, you can validate if both handle the commands and events as expected. If you're looking for reference material on how to test aggregates and sagas, I would recommend you check the Testing section of the documentation.
2. Axon Server / Event Store
Secondly, let's take a look at the event routing issue that you are apparently facing. When building an Event Sourced system as you would with Axon, you need an Event Store. Typically, this is Axon Server in Axon-based applications.
Axon Server is both the storage of your events, as well as the routing of your events. But, before anything can get routed to other (micro)services, the event should first be stored.
Hence, if routing between services doesn't occur, it is always smart to check if the event is actually present in the store. Based on the information you've given, that is not clear to me. Thus, please check if the ModelCreatedEvent is actually stored.
If it isn't, then there is something wrong with publishing the event. However, if this is the case, I would expect you to see exceptions. As you're not sharing any stack traces, I doubt this is the issue.
If it is, then there is something wrong with connecting your Saga-service to Axon Server (or any other store you're using). Perhaps it is looking at a different store? Perhaps it is not connected at all? This would be my best bet, for now.
However, to dive deeper into this, you will have to share:

What event store you're using
The configuration of the aggregate-service to connect to this store.
The configuration of the saga-service to connect to this store.

3. Model Concern
Lastly, I want to address a concern with what your Aggregate and Saga look like. Using a Saga in Axon has a couple of "good practice" rules that I strongly recommend to follow up, being:

You are coordinating actions between several aggregates. Either in the same application or between applications.
The process the saga coordinates is relatively short-lived, or
The process the saga coordinates is straightforward.

If pointer 1 is not the case, it is better to use a regular Event Handling Component. These are much easier and less error-prone to build and debug, so they simplify your development and maintenance live.
If 2 and 3 are not the case, so the saga is both long-lived and complex instead of straightforward, building a single saga class will become pretty rough to deal with. It is not to say you cannot make it work, but this comes back to development, testing, and maintenance afterwards. So, if you are dealing with a complex process, perhaps a BPMN tool would be better suited for the task.
Given the sample code you've drafted, it seems like you're playing around with this style. Based on that code, I cannot clearly state whether you need a saga at all. However, I want to make sure my suggestions on when to use and when not to use Axon Framework's Saga support are given to you, Oğuz.
